# Compile time distribution strategy issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

i have following code- which tries to implement simple Reinforcement learning environment with keras

```
import gym
from gym import Env
import numpy as np
from gym.spaces import Discrete,Box
import random
#create a custom class
class ShowerEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space =Discrete(3) #possible value 0,1,2
        self.observation_space =Box(low=np.float32(np.array([0])),high =np.float32(np.array([100])),dtype=np.float32) #numbers between [0 100] continuous
        self.state =38 + random.randint(-3,3) # temperature range will be between [38-3.38+3]
        self.shower_length =60 #duration of  temperature
    def step(self,shower_action):
        #if action =0, then decrease temperature, if action=1, leave unchanged if action=2, increase
        self.state += shower_action -1
        self.shower_length -=1
        if self.state >=37 and self.state <=39:
            reward =1
        else:
            reward =-1
        if self.shower_length <=0:
            done =True
        else:
            done =False
        info =()
        info ={}
        return self.state,reward,done,info
    def render(self):
        pass
    def reset(self):
        self.state =38+ random.randint(-3,3)
        self.shower_length =60
        return self.state
"""
env =ShowerEnv()
episodes =10
for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
    state =env.reset()
    done =False
    score =0
    while not done :
        action =env.action_space.sample()
        n_state,reward,done,info =env.step(action)
        score +=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
"""
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
env =ShowerEnv()
states =env.observation_space.shape
actions =env.action_space.n
def build_model(states,actions):
    model =Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu',input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
    return model
model =build_model(states,actions)
#del model
#print(model.summary())
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import  BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import  SequentialMemory
def build_agent(model,actions):
    policy =BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory =SequentialMemory(limit=50000,window_length=1)
    dqn =DQNAgent(model=model,memory=memory,policy=policy,nb_actions=actions,nb_steps_warmup=10,target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

i have imported all  keras  parameters from tensorflow library, but it gives me following issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\Shower_Custom_class.py", line 71, in <module>
    dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 167, in compile
    self.target_model = clone_model(self.model, self.custom_model_objects)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\util.py", line 16, in clone_model
    clone.set_weights(model.get_weights())
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 157, in get_weights
    self._compile_time_distribution_strategy)
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_compile_time_distribution_strategy'
```

could you help me please to figure out what is source of mistake?

Answer (score 2):

i found  solution - instead of declaring model before   the putting it to the DQNAgent, i just use functional form like this

```
dqn = build_agent(build_model(states,actions), actions)
dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

and it works fine.full code is given below

```
 import gym
    from gym import Env
    import numpy as np
    from gym.spaces import Discrete,Box
    import random
    #create a custom class
    class ShowerEnv(Env):
        def __init__(self):
            self.action_space =Discrete(3) #possible value 0,1,2
            self.observation_space =Box(low=np.float32(np.array([0])),high =np.float32(np.array([100])),dtype=np.float32) #numbers between [0 100] continuous
            self.state =38 + random.randint(-3,3) # temperature range will be between [38-3.38+3]
            self.shower_length =60 #duration of  temperature
        def step(self,shower_action):
            #if action =0, then decrease temperature, if action=1, leave unchanged if action=2, increase
            self.state += shower_action -1
            self.shower_length -=1
            if self.state >=37 and self.state <=39:
                reward =1
            else:
                reward =-1
            if self.shower_length <=0:
                done =True
            else:
                done =False
            info =()
            info ={}
            return self.state,reward,done,info
        def render(self):
            pass
        def reset(self):
            self.state =38+ random.randint(-3,3)
            self.shower_length =60
            return self.state
    """
    env =ShowerEnv()
    episodes =10
    for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
        state =env.reset()
        done =False
        score =0
        while not done :
            action =env.action_space.sample()
            n_state,reward,done,info =env.step(action)
            score +=reward
        print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
    """
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
    env =ShowerEnv()
    states =env.observation_space.shape
    actions =env.action_space.n
    def build_model(states,actions):
        model =Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu',input_shape=states))
        model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
        return model
    #model =build_model(states,actions)
    #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
    #del model
    #print(model.summary())
    from rl.agents import DQNAgent
    from rl.policy import  BoltzmannQPolicy
    from rl.memory import  SequentialMemory
    def build_agent(model,actions):
        policy =BoltzmannQPolicy()
        memory =SequentialMemory(limit=50000,window_length=1)
        dqn =DQNAgent(model=model,memory=memory,policy=policy,nb_actions=actions,nb_steps_warmup=10,target_model_update=1e-2)
        return dqn
    dqn = build_agent(build_model(states,actions), actions)
    dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose

=1)
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked for me. However, I'm not able to understand why it worked. Can you add more context/detail to the solution?